# Shorten Code in Java when creating objects

Tags: java, string, object, shortcut

Im just wondering if there is a nice shortcut in creating a Scanner object, getting user input and storing it into a variable. cheers

my crappy long code:

```
String userInput;

public String getUserInput(){
    Scanner UI= new Scanner(System.in);
    userInput = UI.nextLine();
    return userInput;
}
```

Comment: if the code works, post it here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your `Scanner` should be initialized once, not every time you need more input.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, there's no reason to reinitialize your Scanner every time you want to get user input.  For example, you can make it an instance variable:

```
Scanner ui = new Scanner(System.in);
```

You also don't need to declare the next line of your Scanner a separate variable within method getUserInput().  If you need it as a variable, you can initialize the variable wherever you call getUserInput().

Write the method like this to be more concise:

```
public String getUserInput() {
    return ui.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The scanner should be initialized only once, as Jashaszun's comment mentions:

```
static final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

The actual input can be read by using several methods, each tailored to a specific type of input. In general, if is a line, and you want to obtain it as a `String`, use this:

```
public String getUserInput() {
    return in.nextLine();
}
```